# KendoUI Grid Pager Icons out of alignment

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Implemented a Kendo Grid exactly as stated in the examples.

Here is the pager in the example:

[image]

Here is my pager:

[image]

Notice how the arrows are right at the top of the buttons.

[image]

Why is it like this? I thought if you install KendoUI that everything should work well out of the box?

I have tried this in Chrome, Firefox and IE and the same results.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The worst part is the refresh on the right hand side, it's completely out of alignment to the item count next to it.

I have even tried a fresh install on a new solution and that did not fix the problem either.

Can someone please help me? Is there perhaps more steps to install Kendo UI properly?

Comment: Does your html page have doctype defined?

Comment: Nope, if you post that as an asnwer I will accept it, @Japi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this similar problem some time ago. After searching problem I found out that I didn't have doctype on my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

My page had DOCTYPE html, however the declaration was set to transitional. I removed this and it worked. It also works if you set it to strict.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Answer (score 0):

This misalignment issue is occurring due to kendo icon property which is set to super.
To resolve the issue, we need to set this to middle

```
 .k-icon
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Include above property in inline css of that page.Like we need to include this into  `<style> </style>`tag.